# WebView2 ExecuteScriptAsync returns null after WebView2 reload

Tags: c#, webview2

I'm writing a Windows Forms app that uses `WebView2` to display a web page and detect changes. I have a timer firing every 10 minutes which triggers this code snippet:

```cs
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView21.Reload();
    String html = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");

    SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create();
    String thisTimeHash = GetHash(hash, html);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("u") + " " + thisTimeHash + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

For reasons I can't explain, `webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync` returns `null` after `webView21.Reload()` is called to refresh the page. If I comment out `webView21.Reload()`, it works just fine and I get back the HTML.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to get this to work?

I tried the following:

```cs
webView21.Reload();
String html = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
```

And was expecting the page HTML. If I comment out `webView21.Reload()`, it works just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinForms Microsoft.Web.WebView2 Navigate, Page Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052640/winforms-microsoft-web-webview2-navigate-page-fully-loaded)

Comment: Thank you @GSerg, that helped! That link helped me figure out it was a timing issue.  Simply adding await Task.Delay(5000) between the Reload and ExecuteScriptAsync fixed it.

(This is not the final code, this is more of a proof of concept that it was a timing issue)

            webView21.Reload();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            String html = string.Empty;
            html = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");